# Server Side Get Request with AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

This api that I am using only allows server side get requests and does not allow for get requests to come directly from the browser. They use basic auth like this `Authorization: Basic YTcxODNlMWI3ZTlhYjA5YjhhNWNmYTg3ZDE5MzRjM2M6`. So as long as you include the  appropriate api key in the header all is well. I set up a get request in Amazon's API Gateway that grabs only the first 500 users (max is 500 that I can return at one time) from the api and returns those to the DOM with my custom url with my api key in the header. I have the ability to set query string parameters like this: `users?page=1&per_page=500`.

Since the api does not return how many pages of users there will be, how do I set up AWS API Gateway in order to scale this? For instance if we have 2400 users, will have to keep going back and creating get requests but with different page numbers or could I use AWS Lambda and pass in the page number as a variable and loop through until the results are less than 500? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hmm i don't know if this is a good idea or not. But what if you use a lambda function that retrieve the number of candidates for that API? e.g. it's called once per hour. You save that number and use it for your pagination reference.

Comment: That Is a good idea. I will try that @KendrickKesley

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think using passing page number and number of result to return (which is 500 in your case ) to lambda function is right way to doing it.